# Starting Camera Intent from a java class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener, android-camera-intent

I am trying to develop an app where the layout is created dynamically.
In my layout, I am creating an`UploadImage` button.

I am creating the `OnClickListener`  in another java class which `implements` the `OnClickListener' class, so that  can use it at different places in my app.

But, Unfortunately, I am unable to start the camera activity.

Below is the source code of my application.

###MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    GenerateViews genView = new GenerateViews();
    genView.addQuestionWithUploadImageOption(this, layout);

}
```

###activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="3dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

###GenerateViews.java

```
public class GenerateViews {

void addQuestionWithUploadImageOption(final Context context,
        LinearLayout layout) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinearLayout layoutImage = new LinearLayout(context);
    layoutImage.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layoutImage.setWeightSum(1);
    layoutImage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setContentDescription("Image");

    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(256, 256));

    Button uploadImageButton = new Button(context);
    uploadImageButton.setText(R.string.uploadImage);

    uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new UploadImage());

    layoutImage.addView(imageView);
    layoutImage.addView(uploadImageButton);

    layout.addView(layoutImage);
}
}
```

From this `GenerateViews` java class, I am calling `UploadImage` class which is actually implementing the OnClickListener.

###UploadImage.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class UploadImage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
}
}
```

Everything is working fine. My form is being created dynamically and all the texts and etc are displayed as I want.
Even the `OnClickListener` is calling the `UploadImage.java` class.
But this the error which I am getting:

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: Which is line number 20 in UploadImage? I think you have not initialize `imageview` before setting bitmap. :)

Comment: @Chintan Rathod Actually this part I will take care of later...but initially, **startActivityForResult** is not starting...it means my app is unable to open the `camera intent`....first the camera must open then ill take care of saving the image or whatsoever.

Comment: You did not set onClick() to any of the button.
Try button.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: @abhishek  then what is this line for??  

`Button uploadImageButton = new Button(context);
    uploadImageButton.setText(R.string.uploadImage);

    uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new UploadImage());
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this project [here](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project) . I havent updated it for quite long time ;) but it will suit your need

**STEPS**

1.Create a new project in android , right click on it and Choose Android and now click add at the bottom to add the "Library" project to your project

2.Place these permission in your Manifest file

```
<uses-features android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

and also this activity under the application tag

```
<activity android:name="com.camera.library.CameraLibrary"></activity>
```

3.Now get the instance of the class

```
 CameraOptions options = CameraOptions.getInstance(this);
 options.takePicture();
```

1. on the click event of button or in any activity call use to start the camera

   Intent intent = new Intent(this,CameraLibrary.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
2. Call the `options.getBitmapFile()` method to get the bitmap image when user takes the picture or use the `options.getFilePath()` method to get the file path

The images created are stored in the cache directory of the application

**EDIT**

Change your code like this

```
public class UploadImage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
private CameraOptions options;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    options = CameraOptions.getInstance(UploadImage.this);
    options.takePicture();
    options.setRequesCode(CAMERA_REQUEST);
    Intent intent = new Intent(UploadImage.this,CameraLibrary.class); 
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(options.getBitmapFile());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: but the problem is....that im calling the camera only from a java class..which is not an activity
if it had been an activity, there would have been no problem.
but since it is a java class...I am unable to use `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Please upvote this question sir...I need a good answer from more number of people..please

Comment: Why don't you use the `startActivityForResult` in `UploadImage class`?. Can you specify exactly what class is calling what class because your saying your calling camera from a java class,and ya i up-voted also. Also please check my EDIT in answer

Comment: where should I instantiate the CameraOptions Class??

Comment: please check the code above..i have clealy said everything...but for you...ill explain again

I am calling `UploadInage` from `GenerateViews` java class
Now, if I wirte `startActivityForResult` in `UploadImage` I am getting error.

I think camera intent can only be started from an activity right??

Comment: `startActivityForResult` can be called from any class that extends `Activity`. Please check the edit of my answer i had shown where to use `CameraOptions` so modify you `UploadImage` class

Comment: is it possible that the class file extending activity is not mentioned in the manifest file as an activity.

Because, I am getting error saying `have you declared the activity in the android manifest`

Comment: The class file extending activity has to be placed in manifest else it will throw that error when you call it,so you have to add it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35182/discussion-between-atish-agrawal-and-girish-nair)

Answer (score 2):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
    {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles())
            {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg"))
                {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try 
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),btmapOptions);
                bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                ivRecipeImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+ "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try 
                {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) 
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, RecipeActivity.this);
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ivRecipeImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use this code and also add "write external storage" permission in menifest

Comment: actually the camera intent is not starting initially.
How will I be able to save the image if I am unable to capture it..
onActivityResult() is a later task..First I want to initialize the camera which is not starting using startActivityForResult().

Comment: please upvote this question so that more people can answer it.

Comment: u have to get file path of captured photo then convert it into bitmap or bytearry then you can save it